# Can someone explain to me why one function works and the other don't?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am working on learning React, I am doing the Road To React book. In the book he used this code

```
const List = (props) => (
    props.list.map(item => (
      <div key={item.objectID}>
            <span>
              <a href={item.url}> {item.title} </a>
            </span>
            <span>
              {item.author}
            </span>
            <span>{item.num_comments} </span>
            <span>{item.points} </span>
          </div>
    ))
  )
```

And I used this code

```
const List = (props) => {
    return props.list.map(item => {
      <div key={item.objectID}>
            <span>
              <a href={item.url}> {item.title} </a>
            </span>
            <span>
              {item.author}
            </span>
            <span>{item.num_comments} </span>
            <span>{item.points} </span>
          </div>
    })
  }
```

His worked and mine did not work, I been researching and I do not understand why, if someone can please help me understand why.

Comment: Everything is correct, but you should add return after props.list.map(item => { return (<div></div>)

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been bothering me, I knew I was missing something lol.

Comment: Hi @brokecoder, please vote up, if this answer adds something useful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you changed curly bracket `(` to just brace `{` here
`...list.map(item => {`
and no return statement before your jsx code.

So, you can change your code to `...list.map(item => (` or just add `return` statement before jsx.

```
...list.map(item => {
    return <div...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the div in your map function.

```
return props.list.map(item => {
       return (<div key={item.objectID}>
            <span>
              <a href={item.url}> {item.title} </a>
            </span>
            <span>
              {item.author}
            </span>
            <span>{item.num_comments} </span>
            <span>{item.points} </span>
          </div>);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

'return' is missing inside the **props.list.map**
Since it is a function, it expects a return statement.

```
const List = (props) => {
    return props.list.map(item => {
      return (<div key={item.objectID}>
            <span>
              <a href={item.url}> {item.title} </a>
            </span>
            <span>
              {item.author}
            </span>
            <span>{item.num_comments} </span>
            <span>{item.points} </span>
          </div>)
    })
  }
```

That should solve the problem!